# How do I fix my trim that wasn’t sanded well

Tags: trim

[image][image]

Trim that was painted was not sanded well and now we have bumps on the painted trim, how do I fix this?!

Comment: That actually looks like a roller finish, which does not lay as flat as a brush (or spray) finish on trim. The only solution is probably sand and recoat, but with a brush and a leveling additive this time.

Comment: I agree with @bib except for the leveling additive is probably not necessary. High quality paint and a professional grade brush should do you just fine.

Comment: I think the question refers to the fastener hole patch, not the paint stipple.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a different tack and assume you're referring to the bumps where the fastener holes were patched. My fix at this point would be to make sure that the paint is thoroughly dry so that it sands well. Then take a random orbit sander and go over those areas again. If you tilt the sander just slightly so as to apply pressure on one edge of the pad  you can sand a fairly small area fairly quickly. You'll have to completely repaint, of course, including any primer coat you may have done before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me, but if you want a smoother finish, replace the trim.

With an in-set groove like that it's not going to be worth the time to sand.  Trash it.

You might want to measure and cut the new trim, then sand it and take it to an autobody shop or clean room for the perfect paint job.